# Solving a matrix initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

> Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with $-3$ and $-1$ as eigenvalues. The eigenvectors are $v_1=[-1,1]$ and $v_2=[1,1]$. Let $x(t)$ be the position of a particle at time $t$.  Solve the initial value problem $x'(t)=Ax$, $x(0)=[2,3]$.

So this should be easy, we set up the system as two ODEs:

\begin{align}
x'(t) &= -e^{-3t}+e^{-t} \\
y'(t) &= e^{-3t}+e^{-t}
\end{align}

Integrating each eqn.:

\begin{align}
x(t) &= 3e^{-3t}-e^{-t} \\
y(t) &=-3e^{-3t}-e^{-t}
\end{align}

But without the coefficients there is nothing to discover.  So I insert the coefficients:

\begin{align}
x(t) &= C_13e^{-3t}-C_2e^{-t} \\
y(t) &=-C_13e^{-3t}-C_2e^{-t}
\end{align}

and apply the initial conditions:

\begin{align}
2 &= 3C_1-C_2 \\
3 &=-3C_1-C_2
\end{align}

but this gives:

\begin{align}
\frac{2+C_2}{3} &= C_1 \\
3 &= -2
\end{align}

which is clearly incorrect.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Check your linear system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood something from the start. The matrix $A$ is not explicitly given. From what is known of the general solution, you get
$$
\pmatrix{x\\y}=c_1v_1e^{-3t}+c_2v_2e^{-t}.
$$
There is no further differentiation or integration required. Just the solution of the linear system for the initial values
$$
\pmatrix{2\\3}=c_1\pmatrix{-1\\1}+c_2\pmatrix{1\\1}
\\~\\
2=-c_1+c_2\\
3=c_1+c_2
$$
which should be easily found as $c_1=0.5$ and $c_2=2.5$

Comment: Thanks Lutz, this was great.

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake when you solved the linear system. Adding the two equations gives $5 = -2C_2$, hence $C_2 = -\frac{5}{2}$. Plugging this into one of the equations, we obtain $C_1 = -\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Thanks, though a simple small mistake, now at the least, we have a full example of solving a matrix equation with a correct procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Where you claim you “integrated each eqn.”, you actually **differenciated them instead:**

\begin{align}
x(t) &= \frac13 e^{-3t}-e^{-t} \\
y(t) &=-\frac13 e^{-3t}-e^{-t}
\end{align}

The system for the constants after applying the initial conditions becomes:

\begin{align}
2 &= \frac13 C_1-C_2 \\
3 &=-\frac13 C_1-C_2
\end{align}

Add both to get $5=-2C_2$, then substract the second from the first to get $-1=\frac23 C_1$. Hence,
$$C_1 = -\frac32, \quad C_2 = -\frac52.$$